# Migrate MS-Access tables with Regular Expression in Validation Rule to SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server, regex, ms-access

I'm migrating a MS-Access .accdb-database to SQL Server 2017. In my MS Access database, there is a lot of table columns with validation rule like "NOT LIKE *[!a-z0-9.]*". I cannot find any way to add a constraint in SQL Server that do the same thing. Is there a way to do this, or is it simply impossible to migrate MS Access to SQL-Server without losing functionality?

```
ALTER TABLE [Zones]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [CHK_Zon]
        CHECK ([Zon] NOT LIKE '*[!a-z0-9.]*')
```

Comment: Try to replace ´*´ by ´%´ and ´?´ by ´_´.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: ... and also replace the ´!´ by ´^´, like @larnu suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
NOT LIKE '%[^a-z0-9.]%'
```

This will mean that only the letters `a` to `z`, the numerals `0` to `9` and the character `.` will be allowed. Note that all or some upper case letters may be allowed, depending on your collation, and all lowercase letters, with `a-z`.

`%` are multi-character wildcards.

The `^` (carat) symbol means *"Any single character not within the specified range"*. So, for example, `'Test' NOT LIKE '%[^A-z]%'` would return TRUE, as it only contains the characters in the range `A-z` (it doesn't contain any outside of it.

SQL Server does not support Regex (not natively anyway, it can by use of CLR functions), it only has simply pattern matching; which you can read about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments).

Comment: So "SQL Server does not support Regex" means that its impossible to migrate all MS Access functionality to SQL-Server?

Comment: The whole statement was *"SQL Server does not support Regex (**not natively anyway, it can by use of CLR functions**)"* (Added emphasis to relevant part). MS-Access and SQL Server are different products. You shouldn't expect the 2 to be identical and have the same functionality as the other out of the box. They doesn't mean you can't replicate that functionality by some other method.

Comment: Well, I’m not expecting anything, I just thought that I’m not the first one to facing this problem when migrating from Access to SQL-Server. Maybe someone else has a workaround. Adding CLR functions seems a bit complicated, but if that’s the only way, then I have to do that.

Comment: Either way, for the simple expression you have, @andarvi, the pattern matching SQL Server does have will suffice.

Comment: Access does not support Regex and never did. So it has a basic pattern matching ability - exactly what was posted in this soluion